# Why doesn't specifying the full path of an mp4 in video file work when relative path does using PHP on apache/Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: php, video, path, scandir

I've got a number of mp4 video files in a folder.  When I use `scandir` with a relative path, the files display correctly in the webpage and can be played.

Browser html looks like this.

```
<div class="box">
<video src="./mp4Files/video1.mp4" type="video/mp4" loop class="clip" controls
</video>
</div>
```

When I specify the full path of the file, scandir finds the files, the browser constructs the videos in a  but the error appears - no video with supported format and MIME type found.

Browser html looks like

```
<div class="box">
    <video src="/var/www/html/VideoRecTest/mp4Files/video1.mp4" type="video/mp4" loop    
    class="clip" controls></video>
 </div>
```

btw, `open_base_dir` has no value when I do a `phpinfo()`.

Comment: `/var/www/html/VideoRecTest/` is not accessible to a browser. It should be `http://domain/documentroot`. In your case I would guess `http://www.example.com/VideoRecTest/mp4Files/video1.mp4` ... possibly with `https` if you are using encrypted connections.

Comment: Thanks that helps. Gist of my issue is that my mp4 files are coming from a different directory at a higher level than "VideoRecTest'.  They will come from another drive mounted under /media.  Is that possible?  If so, how would I specify?

Comment: Why would that be possible, `html`/`php`/`js` etc... are not `webservers`. Your webserver listens for a connection and serves a public directory at `ip/` or `dns/` with a root directory. `/var/www/...` (the root dir in your configuration) is not served here and would actually interpret `/var/www/html/var/www/html....`

Answer (score 0):

These are not webservers

- `html`
- `php`
- `javascript`

These are webservers

- `nginx`
- `apache2`

Your webserver's `vhost` configuration will contain a path that is served as the root directory.

`/var/www/html/` becomes `0.0.0.0/` or `example.com/`.

When you then want to visit, for example `index.php` the URI would be `0.0.0.0/index.php` which uses `/var/www/html/index.php`.

Your use-case here is configured at `/var/www/html` and thus giving a path of `/var/www/html/VideoRecTest/mp4Files/video1.mp4` would merely give an absolute path of

```
/var/www/html/var/www/html/VideoRecTest/mp4Files/video1.mp4
```

Your video would, however, be accessible perfectly fine just at

```
/VideoRecTest/mp4Files/video1.mp4
```

Since your `webserver` is already configured to serve directories and files from the root directory `/var/www/html`.

You also cannot traverse below the specified root directory. `0.0.0.0/../` will translate to `/var/www/html/` and thus redirect back to `0.0.0.0/`.

Note, the root directory can be changed in your vhost configuration. I use `/var/www/html` as an example due to it being the default.

Comment: This is super helpful.  Much appreciated.  Not the answer I wanted, but I understand next steps.  Thanks.

Comment: You can use PHP to traverse below the `/var/www/html` path, just not the webserver via a request.